# keep out line break

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, newlines, special-characters

I have some files with this structure:

```
2015-03-25 17:08:17
sysUpTimeInstance 93474;^M
1.ValueforState=2500
```

I want to replace the line break, and leave the third line with the second line, I mean, the output would be like this:

```
2015-03-25 17:08:17
sysUpTimeInstance 93474;1.ValueforState=2500
```

I tried with sed:

```
sed 's/^M$//' myfile.dat > mynewfile.dat
```

But it only removed the symbol ^M

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

2 thoughts:

1. with sed, for any line that ends with a carriage return, join the next line

   ```
   sed '/\r$/ {N; s/\r\n//} ' file
   ```
2. with awk, define the record separator for input and output:

   ```
   awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='' 1 file
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what shows up as `^M` in your post really is a carriage return character (`\r`), the following should do the job:

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n//g'
```

It will work no matter how many lines your input contains: all lines ending with `\r\n` will be joined with the line that follows.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things could be happening.

If the `^M` is not actually the 2 charecters `^` and `M`, but is the way some editors can represent the Carriage Return (CR) character. eg. My Emacs editor shows it as such. This character is part of the `end-of-line` character pair in Windows file system: a Carriage Return (hex value 0x0D) + a New Line (hex value 0x0A). The New Line character is also known as a Line Feed. The Unix file system uses only the New Line character to end a line. To remove an unwanted Carriage Return at the end of a Unix-style line, using `sed` you can use the following regular expression: Note `\x0D` and `\r` both work in `sed`.  Note: `\r` is a shorthand way to represent `0x0D`.

```
sed '/\r$/{N; s/\r\n//}'
```

If `^M` is actually the two characters `^` and `M`, which can happen sometimes when a Windows file in incorrectly converted into a Unix-style file, then you must handle the `^` as a special regular-expression character; you must `escape` it with a backslash `\`: Use this `sed` command:

```
sed '/\^M$/{N; s/\^M\n//}'
```

Answer (score 0):

^M looks for me like its a DOS file

If ^M is really ASCII 13 (0x09) and not ASCII 94+77 (0x5E+0x4D) try to use:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/^M\n//g' myfile.dat > mynewfile.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just three lines, and you always want to join the second and third line, you can use this:

```
sed -e '2N' -e 's/\r\n//'
```

the N command will add the next line (i.e. the third) to the second, and then the replacing will remove the linebreak.